# mpd & gmpc problem

Tags: mpd

I have two computers, both running Ubuntu, one 15.10, the other 16.04.

The 15.10 machine has mpd (version 0.19.10 from the repository) installed on it, this computer is to act as the music server.  It also has pulseaudio.

The 16.04 machine is the client, it has version 11.8.16 of GMPC installed on it.

On the 15.10 server machine, I have mpd running and using port 6600, but not as the mpd user, as you can see:

---

main19@system19:~$ lsof -i :6600

COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

mpd     4808 main19    9u  IPv4  37244      0t0  TCP localhost:6600 (LISTEN)

---

When I run mpc update, I get this output, I don't know if this tells me anything useful:

---

main19@system19:/$ mpc update
Updating DB (#2) ...
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off

---

(I *guess* mpd is installed and running correctly on the 15.10 machine, but I don't know how I can know that for sure.)

On the 16.04 client machine, in GMPC, in the connection settings under preferences, I am using the ip address of the 15.10 server machine, with a port of 6600, and the path on the 15.10 server that contains the music files.

On the 16.04 client machine, when I start up GMPC, I get this error message:

error code 13:  problems connecting to "192.168.1.19" on port 6600:  operation now in progress

I don't know what to make of that.  It just remains stuck at that.

My question:  How do I go about intelligently figuring out what is wrong with my mpd and/or gmpc installation and configuration?